# How to update the "Description" column of existing user-defined data types?

Tags: postgresql

Say I have an existing user-defined data type like this:

```
my_db=# create type foo as (id int);
CREATE TYPE
my_db=# \dT+ foo
                                     List of data types
 Schema  | Name | Internal name | Size  | Elements | Owner | Access privileges | Description 
--------+------+---------------+-------+----------+-------+-------------------+-------------
 schema  | foo  | foo           | tuple |          | user  |                   | 
(1 row)

my_db=#
```

Can I update the `Description` column in any way? I thought about [`alter type`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertype.html) but there was nothing on there about the `Description` column, so I wondered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`COMMENT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-comment.html):

> Comments can be viewed using psql's `\d` family of commands. Other user interfaces to retrieve comments can be built atop the same built-in functions that psql uses, namely `obj_description`, `col_description`, and `shobj_description`...

```
comment on type foo is 'whatever';
```

Comment: I didn't know about comment at all, just tried it out and it worked. I'll definitely read up on it.